How to resolve Swift Package dependency which requires additional authentication?
I've created a Swift package for an xcframework we're unable to include in our git repo (doing so breaks the signature). The Swift package has only a .binaryTarget which is hosted on our JFrog account as a zipped archive. I am able to download the archive using curl -v --progress-bar -u $JFROG_USERNAME:$JFROG_PASSWORD -L https://myCompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/binaries/path/to/xcframework.zip -o framework.zip. I can access the Swift package (hosted in our GitHub Enterprise account) through Xcode but get a failed downloading 'https://myCompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/binaries/path/to/xcframework.zip' which is required by binary target 'myTarget': badResponseStatusCode (401) error when Xcode tries to download the framework.
I've tried using the https url for the package and selecting the package from the GitHub source control account list in Xcode's add package workflow. I've also tried adding an entry in my .netrc for myCompany.jfrog.io (from discussion here https://forums.swift.org/t/spm-support-basic-auth-for-non-git-binary-dependency-hosts/37878/7) but that did not change the outcome.
Is it possible to download a Swift package dependency in Xcode that requires additional authentication?
We need a solution that supports individual developers as well as CI/CD through GitHub Actions.

Did you find a solution?

In my case, it improved the situation by running this command on my spm repo folder:
swift package resolve --verbose

By doing so, I would get all the artifacts needed for that spm downloaded, with terminal messages like:

info: credentials for https://foo.zip found in netrc file at /Users/username/.netrc

or

Fetching binary artifact https://foo.zip from cache

And since SPM seems to keep a cache of every version downloaded inside
~/Library/Developer/Caches/

If I now go into my project using that SPM, and I added and reset package caches a few times, one of them did work for me.
It looks as if the issue is not really the download itself and that the 401 is not really that.
Who knows. Also I blame ESET a bit. Not sure if it's Sequoia, Xcode16, ESET or something else. But this was definitely not an issue before. And it ran unnoticed since I had my artifacts in my cache. The issue only surfaced when these caches were cleaned up.
Edit: I also posted in apple discussions (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255808229?answerId=260901758022&sortBy=rank#260901758022) and I got this suggestion from oscar-wcar that might be worth trying. Not sure if this solves it entirely as it's not happening to me once I did my initial solution, but it might work for others: set your .netrc file permissions to 0600 (mine was 0640):
$ chmod 600 .netrc

I hope this helps someone out there, feeling alone and in complete darkness.
